# OpenX Alternative for wordpress?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, adsense

I'm looking for advertising manager so i can handle all the ads, and AdSense units in one place.
 i used open until now but its seems they are going to deprecate their system (the open source one) - what are you using then?

Comment: I'm thinking that this question might do better on the webmaster stackexchange site, as it's really of general interest to an website owner who servers ads, rather that specific to WordPress.

Comment: I disagree, the question is essentially how to achieve specific functionality (equal or similar to OpenX) in WordPress. OpenX is hosted solution, WP analogue would be plugin - not external service.

Comment: @Rarst but how is the question **constructive** under the defined WPSE Q & A format? I agree with marfarma that the question could use better clarification to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Google DFP Small business is free and pretty much the only alternative to OpenX

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OpenX but I recently implemented the [Simple Ads Manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-ads-manager/) for a client who wanted banner ads on their site. It handles DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) and arbitrary HTML/JS so you should be able to use AdSense as well.